# Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 "hangs" at random

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, visual-studio-2022

I have a problem when using latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (version 17.2.2) running on Windows 10 Enterprise (Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044, if that matters). The problem is that the Visual Studio "hangs" at random moments, but not completely. By that I mean that it looks like everything's fine with it, but I just can't click it. By fine I mean that for example when I'm debugging an application and VS hangs, the app is running completely normal, everything's showing up in VS and for example breakpoints are hit normally. When it happens, I can also close VS from the task bar normally and it unloads everything peacefully. Like I said - everything's completely normal, but it's like VS is behind a glass. Also, like I said - it's completely random and sometimes it hangs when VS is in the background, but it also happens when I'm writing and it freezes mid word. The cursor is flashing, but I can't type anything and VS doesn't respond to keyboard and mouse clicks.

It's not that big of a problem, but it is quite annoying nevertheless, especially when it happens few times a day, about once every 2 hours.

<s>The weird thing about it is that it only happens when I'm doing stuff in a specific project - a VSTO plugin for Outlook written in C# (hence the tags). I can have multiple windows (and solutions) opened at one, but when it happens, only one of them freezes - and it's the window with the VSTO plugin for Outlook. I don't know if that's the problem with the solution/project or if it's something with Visual Studio.</s>

Like I said - it's not that big of a deal, as I can just close it from the taskbar, but it is quite frustrating and I'd like to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: More than a month has passed and I think this question needs to be updated. During that month I updated everything - Visual Studio to version 17.2.5, ReSharper (more on that later) to version 2022.1.2 (from version 2022.1.0) and Windows to version 21H2. And nothing helped. However I have some observations that I think I have to share.

First of all - answering matthew-watson's question - yes, there is a plugin involved and it's the aforementioned ReSharper. I feel quite stupid, because I completely forgot that I had it installed since I started using this PC - I just didn't use it. When I started using it nothing (in terms of this question) has changed - because it has always been there. However I'm not sure if ReSharper is here to blame - at least not completely. I tried disabling it few times during that month and it seemed liked it helped, because there were no "freezes" when it was disabled. Usually after few hours I turned it back on - I like ReSharper and I'd rather not stop using it. But I'm not sure it really helped - maybe it is just so happened that there were no "freezes" when it was disabled, that it was pure accident, as there were days when ReSharper was enabled and there were no occurrences of this bug. Moreover other people in my office are using the same configuration as me (same PC, same software - including the same version of Visual Studio, ReSharper and Windows) and they don't have this bug. I'm starting to wonder if my PC is cursed...

Secondly - it's not just Office VSTO plugins that cause those "freezes" (hence I crossed that section out). Since I asked this question I changed the project that I'm actively working on and observed that the bug also happens in other projects. It doesn't matter what project, it happens in all of them - simple console projects, Blazor projects etc. However I am quite sure that it happens more often in VSTO projects. Recently I came back to the VSTO project I had been working on previously and the bug happened at least 5 times on one day. In other projects it happens rarer. Though - as mentioned in the original post - it is completely random. There are days when it doesn't happen at all and days when it happens every 30 minutes or so. It's really frustrating. But - as mentioned - it happens more often in Office VSTO plugins for some reason.

Also - I did try repairing Visual Studio by choosing "Repair" option from Visual Studio Installer - it didn't help.

At this point I kinda gave up on solving it - I tried every solution that came to my mind, checked everything and I couldn't find anything - neither a reason for this bug to happen, nor a solution. If one could at least point to where to search for the correct logs and how to debug this problem, I would be thankful.

EDIT 2: Another 2 weeks have passed and I'm sad to have to tell you that this question will have to remain unsolved. I have left the company that I worked for in which I had this problem and so I won't be able to test any solution. Especially that it was only I that got this "freezing" problem, so I won't be able to ask my ex-work colleagues to confirm that any solution posted here managed to solve the mystery and fix the problem.

If anyone gets the same problem, I hope you will be able to fix it and share some details with us. I'm really curious as to what might have been causing it.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed, e.g. Resharper?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, Resharper, but I only installed it recently and the problem was there before I installed it. Other that Resharper I have nothing installed. So I don't think extensions are the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to disable all extensions in VS? Did you try to repair VS?

Comment: In my case I had a Resources folder with thousands of files in it. The problem started after  it grew large. Excluding that folder from the solution solved the problem. I hope it helps you too.